# How do I get my keyboard to not block the content

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

Image of a showBottomModalSheet widget blocked out by the keyboard.`                              ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
showModalBottomSheet(
context: context,
builder: (context) => Wrap(
children: [withdrawSheet()],
));
},
child: const Text('Withdraw'))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G6Mb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Wraps it inside SingleChildScrollView to push the BottomSheet from bottom and thus preventing keyboard from overlapping.